# Generating C code from matlab code implemented using Python Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I was comparing Matlab with Python Scipy, Numpy and Matlplot. I searched the net and found many people were in favor of Python over Matlab. I don't know whether Python is full replacement of Matlab but I want to ask a particular question. In Matlab, you can generate C code corresponding to your Matlab program. I want to know whether this provision is there in Python Scipy as well. So if a user had implemented some thing using Python over Matlab, will it still be possible to generate C Code out of it?

Comment: Is the concern about speed or about hiding code?

Comment: This is about code not sped, i have other set of applications purely written in C/C++ and requires this piece of C code such that it can be integrated in it.

Comment: Which way do you want to do the integrating? The python into the other applications or the other applications into the python (there are too many its and I have grown confused)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write python code to run at C speed using [Cython](http://cython.org/).
Cython basically convert python code to C code under the hood and then compile to a C library compatible with python (so you can "import module").